# Help ! I am not able to create this table

Tags: tables, longtable

I am looking for ways to create this table

```
%\vspace*{0.3cm}
\begin{quadro}[!htbp]
    \begin{footnotesize}
        \captionsetup{textfont=bf, font=footnotesize, justification=centering}
        \caption {Maquinas, equipamentos, móveis e utensílios.} 
        \label{Tabela: Tabela maquinas e equipamentos}
        \vspace*{0.05cm}
        \footnotesize
        %\centering
        %\rowcolors[]{1}{white}{cyan}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{6mm} m{30mm}|P{15mm}|m{18mm}|m{18mm}|}\hline
                 \multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{36mm}|}{\textbf{DESCRIÇÃO}}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}|}{\textbf{QUANT.}}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{18mm}|}{\textbf{VALOR UND.}}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{18mm}|}{\textbf{VALOR TOTAL}} \\ \hline
                & Cadeira comum & 12 & R\$350,00    & R\$4.200,00       \\ \hline
                & Cadeira G     & 11 & R\$2.000,00  & R\$22.000,00      \\ \hline
                & Mesa reun     & 01 & R\$14.000,00 & R\$14.000,00      \\ \hline
            Cadeira comum   &           &           &           &       \\ \hline
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hline
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hline
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hline
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hline
                &           &           &           &       \\ 
                &           &           & Subtotal  &       \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{6mm}|}{\textbf{*}}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm}|}{\textbf{DESCRIÇÃO}}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}|}{\textbf{QUANT.}}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{18mm}|}{\textbf{VALOR UND.}}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{18mm}|}{\textbf{VALOR TOTAL}} \\ \hline
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hhline{|~|----}
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hhline{~|----}
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hhline{~|----}
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hhline{~|----}
                \multirowcell{2}&           &           &           &       \\ \hhline{~|----}
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hhline{~|----}
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hhline{~|----}
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hhline{~|----}
                &           &           &           &       \\ \hhline{~|----}
                &           &           &           &       \\ 
                &           &           & Subtotal  &       \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{threeparttable}
        \vspace*{-0.2cm}
        \par
        \bigskip
        Fonte: Elaborado pelo autor (2021).
    \end{footnotesize}
\end{quadro}
\par
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `MWE` in full format? i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Which document class do you employ? How wide is the text block? Which fonts do you employ, at which size? How or where is the `cuadro` environment defined? Which table-related packaged do you employ? Please advise.

Comment: what is your actual question? You posted some code that we can not run using many undefined commands such as `quadro` and `\captionsetup` and show an image of some output.

Comment: Suggestion (apart from clarify the question): Do not make tables  with jailed data. Avoid all vertical lines  and as many horizontal lines as possible (and preferably use the `booktabs` package for the horizontal lines).

Comment: Which document class do you employ? 
The abntex2 class is based on the memoir class

How wide is the text block?
156mm

Which fonts do you employ, at which size?
Times New Roman, 12pt 
@Mico

Comment: \newcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\listofquadrosname}{Lista de Quadros}

\newfloat[chapter]{quadro}{loq}{\quadroname}
\newlistof{listofquadros}{loq}{\listofquadrosname}
\newlistentry{quadro}{loq}{0}

% configurações para atender às regras da ABNT
\counterwithout{quadro}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftquadroname}{\quadroname\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftquadroaftersnum}{\hfill--\hfill}
% agora a lista de quadro eh negrito
\renewcommand{\cftquadrofont}{\bfseries}

@DavidCarlisle

Comment: Which table-related packaged do you employ?
The same ones you used
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable} @Mico

Comment: Thanks @Zarko
I appreciated your work

Comment: don't add code to comments (as you see, it doesn't really work) you could have edited your code in the question like the code in Zarko's answer, complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` so people can run it and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear, what is your problem. SO, please, extend your code fragment to complete, compilable small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), as it is done in this answer. Also populate your table with more date, especial in the second part.

Anyway, some suggestion, how you can write your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{array, makecell, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}%\uppercase
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mc{O{c|}m}{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{l|}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcll{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{|l|}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \small
    \captionsetup{textfont=bf, font=footnotesize, justification=centering}
\caption {Maquinas, equipamentos, móveis e utensílios.}
\label{Tabela: Tabela maquinas e equipamentos}
%
\sisetup{group-four-digits,
         output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{|l l |S[table-format=2]|S[table-format=5.2]|S[table-format=5.2]|}
    \hline
\mcll[2]{\thead{DESCRIÇÃO}}
                        & \mc{\thead{QUANT.}}
                                & \mc{\thead{VALOR\\ UND. (R\$)}}
                                            & \mc{\thead{VALOR\\ TOTAL (R\$)}} \\
    \hline
        & Cadeira comum & 12    &    350,00 &  4 200,00 \\ \hline
        & Cadeira G     & 11    &  2 000,00 & 22 000,00 \\ \hline
        & Mesa reun     & 01    & 14 000,00 & 14 000,00 \\ \hline
\makecell{Cadeira\\ comum}
        &               &       &           &           \\ \hline
\mcll[2]{Very very long text}
                        &       &           &           \\ \hline
        &               &       &           &           \\ \hline
        &               &       &           &           \\ \hline
        &               &       & Subtotal  &           \\
    \hline
\mcll{\thead{*}}
        & \thead{DESCRIÇÃO}
                        & \mc{\thead{QUANT.}}
                                & \mc{\thead{VALOR\\ UND. (R\$)}}
                                            & \mc{\thead{VALOR\\ TOTAL (R\$)}} \\
    \hline
\mcll{?}  & ???         &       &           &           \\ \cline{2-5}
\mcll{}   &             &       &           &           \\ \cline{2-5}
\mcll{}   &             &       &           &           \\ \cline{2-5}
\mcll{}   &             &       &           &           \\ \cline{2-5}
\mcll{}   &             &       & Subtotal  &           \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushright,para]
\item[] Fonte: Elaborado pelo autor (2021).
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would consider @Fran comments. In this case table will have more professional look and also the table code is simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}%\uppercase
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \small
    \captionsetup{textfont=bf, font=footnotesize, justification=centering}
\caption {Maquinas, equipamentos, móveis e utensílios.}
\label{Tabela: Tabela maquinas e equipamentos}
%
\sisetup{group-four-digits,
         output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l l S[table-format=2] S[table-format=5.2] S[table-format=5.2] }
    \toprule
\mc[2]{\thead{DESCRIÇÃO}}
                        & \mc{\thead{QUANT.}}
                                & \mc{\thead{VALOR\\ UND. (R\$)}}
                                            & \mc{\thead{VALOR\\ TOTAL (R\$)}} \\
    \midrule
        & Cadeira comum & 12    &    350,00 &  4 200,00 \\ 
        & Cadeira G     & 11    &  2 000,00 & 22 000,00 \\ 
        & Mesa reun     & 01    & 14 000,00 & 14 000,00 \\ 
\makecell{Cadeira\\ comum}   
        &               &       &           &           \\ 
\mc[2]{Very very long text}
                        &       &           &           \\ 
        &               &       &           &           \\ 
        &               &       &           &           \\
    \midrule 
        &               &       & Subtotal  &           \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\thead{*}
        & \thead{DESCRIÇÃO}
                        & \mc{\thead{QUANT.}}
                                & \mc{\thead{VALOR\\ UND. (R\$)}}
                                            & \mc{\thead{VALOR\\ TOTAL (R\$)}} \\
    \midrule
?       & ???           &       &           &           \\
        &               &       &           &           \\
        &               &       &           &           \\
    \midrule
        &               &       & Subtotal  &           \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushright,para]
\item[] Fonte: Elaborado pelo autor (2021).
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]